# How to get total files inside a oneDrive folder and its subfolders?

Tags: onedrive

Is there a way to find the total files inside a oneDrive folder and its sub folders ? I tried oneDrive web app,ios app,android app they only display size not total files.Could you guys help me find total files because I want to verify that i downloaded all the files by comparing the total files number .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you just use Properties on the OneDrive folder?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I used Properties on oneDrive web app and it does not show total files inside sub folders! I even tried ios and and android apps!

Comment: If your question is about OneDrive on iOS or Android then your question is out of scope.  Only a question about the OneDrive desktop application is within scope.